# Wait until AWS Glue crawler has finished running

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

In the documentation, I cannot find any way of checking the run status of a crawler. The only way I am doing it currently is constantly checking AWS to check if the file/table has been created.

Is there a better way to block until crawler finishes its run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boto3 (or similar) to do it. There is the get_crawler method. You will find needed information in "LastCrawl" section

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_crawler

Answer (score 22):

The following function uses `boto3`. It starts the AWS Glue crawler and waits until its completion. It also logs the status as it progresses. It was tested with Python v3.8 with boto3 v1.17.3.

```py
import logging
import time
import timeit

import boto3

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def run_crawler(crawler: str, *, timeout_minutes: int = 120, retry_seconds: int = 5) -> None:
    """Run the specified AWS Glue crawler, waiting until completion."""
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072347/
    timeout_seconds = timeout_minutes * 60
    client = boto3.client("glue")
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    abort_time = start_time + timeout_seconds

    def wait_until_ready() -> None:
        state_previous = None
        while True:
            response_get = client.get_crawler(Name=crawler)
            state = response_get["Crawler"]["State"]
            if state != state_previous:
                log.info(f"Crawler {crawler} is {state.lower()}.")
                state_previous = state
            if state == "READY":  # Other known states: RUNNING, STOPPING
                return
            if timeit.default_timer() > abort_time:
                raise TimeoutError(f"Failed to crawl {crawler}. The allocated time of {timeout_minutes:,} minutes has elapsed.")
            time.sleep(retry_seconds)

    wait_until_ready()
    response_start = client.start_crawler(Name=crawler)
    assert response_start["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200
    log.info(f"Crawling {crawler}.")
    wait_until_ready()
    log.info(f"Crawled {crawler}.")
```

Optional bonus: Function to create or update an AWS Glue crawler using some reasonable defaults:

```py
def ensure_crawler(**kwargs: Any) -> None:
    """Ensure that the specified AWS Glue crawler exists with the given configuration.

    At minimum the `Name` and `Targets` keyword arguments are required.
    """
    # Use defaults
    assert all(kwargs.get(k) for k in ("Name", "Targets"))
    defaults = {
        "Role": "AWSGlueRole",
        "DatabaseName": kwargs["Name"],
        "SchemaChangePolicy": {"UpdateBehavior": "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE", "DeleteBehavior": "DELETE_FROM_DATABASE"},
        "RecrawlPolicy": {"RecrawlBehavior": "CRAWL_EVERYTHING"},
        "LineageConfiguration": {"CrawlerLineageSettings": "DISABLE"},
    }
    kwargs = {**defaults, **kwargs}

    # Ensure crawler
    client = boto3.client("glue")
    name = kwargs["Name"]
    try:
        response = client.create_crawler(**kwargs)
        log.info(f"Created crawler {name}.")
    except client.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException:
        response = client.update_crawler(**kwargs)
        log.info(f"Updated crawler {name}.")
    assert response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the most recent AWS docs, you'd also use a [custom waiter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-demo_tools-custom_waiter.py.html) to create a status crawler waiter. A MWE of how use it for this purpose is shown below:

```py
from enum import Enum
from customwaiter import CustomWaiter
import logging
import boto3
import botocore

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CrawlerState(Enum):
    READY = "failure"
    STOPPING = "success"
    RUNNING = "running"
    
class CrawlerStateWaiter(CustomWaiter):
    def __init__(self, client):
        super().__init__(
            "CrawlerState",
            "get_crawler",
            "Crawler.State",
            {"STOPPING": CrawlerState.STOPPING, "READY": CrawlerState.READY},
            client,
            max_tries=100,
        )

    def wait(self, Name):
        self._wait(Name=Name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
    response = glue_client.start_crawler(
        Name=CrawlerName
    )
    assert response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200
    waiter = CrawlerStateWaiter(glue_client)
    waiter.wait(Name=CrawlerName)
    crawler_info = glue_client.get_crawler(
        Name=CrawlerName
    )
    assert crawler_info["Crawler"]["LastCrawl"]["Status"] == "SUCCEEDED"
```

Here the following assumptions were made:

1. Once the crawler is running it won't take long until the crawler changes from `STOPPING`  to `READY`.
2. In order to check whether the crawler performed successfully, I'm assuming that right after finishing this action would be available.

Comment: Hello Miguel, i'm relatively new to aws. i have created your code for calling the crawler and also placed the custom_waiter.py in the same path. How to call the call from this above job? it will be helpful for me as well as newbies like me. Thanks

Comment: @Maharaj I believe I couldn't fully understand your question, however, once you create your was custom service (i.e. CrawlerStateWaiter object) you'd only create a waiter object like this: waiter = CrawlerStateWaiter(<service_client>), where service_client is you boto client.