# How to include AWS Glue crawler in Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

This is my requirement:
I have a crawler and a pyspark job in AWS Glue. I have to setup the workflow using step function.

Questions:

1. How can I add Crawler as the first state. What are the parameters I need to provide(Resource,Type etc).
2. How to make sure that the next state - Pyspark job starts only once the crawler ran successfully.
3. Is there any way I can schedule the Step Function State Machine to run at a particular time?

References:

- [Manage AWS Glue Jobs with Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-glue.html)

Comment: have you checked out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-multiple-etl-jobs-using-aws-step-functions-and-aws-lambda/ ?

Comment: no mention of crawler - Step Function integration

Comment: So, there is no api or resources to start a crawler in StepFunction. What I did: Scheduled the crawler to run at a particular time. Create a cloudwatch rule to trigger a lambda if crawler has succeeded.Then triggered the step function wich had my glue job

Comment: It doesn't still seem to be supported directly. I would indirectly run it via AWS Batch or Fargate.

Comment: @AswinKs Hi from your last comment ` Create a cloudwatch rule to trigger a lambda if crawler has succeeded.Then triggered the step function wich had my glue job` why you need a lambda in the middle? Why not `schedule the srawler->if successfully run->cloudwatch rule triggers the stepfunction with Glue job`?

Answer (score 5):

A few months late to answer this but this can be done from within the step function. 
You can create the following states to achieve it:

- `TriggerCrawler`: Task State: Triggers a Lambda function, within this lambda function you can write code for triggering AWS Glue Crawler using any of the aws-sdk
- `PollCrawlerStatus`: Task state: Lambda function that polls for Crawler status and returns it as a response of lambda.
- `IsCrawlerRunSuccessful`: Choice State: Based on that status of Glue crawler you can make Next state to be a Choice state which will either go to the next state that triggers yours Glue job (once the Glue crawler state is 'READY') or go to the `Wait State` for few seconds before you poll for it again.
- `RunGlueJob`: Task State: A Lambda function that triggers the glue job.
- `WaitForCrawler`: Wait State: That waits for 'n' seconds before you poll for status again.
- `Finish`: Succeed State.

Here is how this Step Function will look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate or post some references on how I can do it?

Comment: I don't have any reference for this. I wrote it myself in my personal aws account.

Comment: Can you post the basic codes of step functions and the lambda functions? That would be helpful.

Comment: I just created this flow diagram using pass and choice state to show here. I don't have any sample code for lambda as that can easily be found on internet.

Comment: You don't strictly need so many state transitions, each of which adds to the cost. A simple ECS or Batch job will do it in a single step, and it will be no more complicated than your Lambda trigger.

Comment: @Acumenus Hi from your comment ` A simple ECS or Batch job will do it in a single step`, do you mind sharing any example codes?

Comment: @Cecilia [This `boto3` using function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072347/) will do it.

Comment: Thanks, I've a quick follow0up question, is crawler & creating a database in Lake Formation required for creating a glue job? For example, I only want to test pyspark script for one single input .txt file, I store it in S3, do I still need crawler? Can I just use `boto3` to create a glue job to test the script and do some preprocessing and write data back to s3?

Comment: @Cecilia I don't really know but I think you can. Try it.

Comment: @Cecilia no it isn't. You can use a glue job to pull data from S3 and write back to S3 without using Lake Formation in between. Check out Glue Studio which lets you set the input/output locations as S3 or in your Data Catalog (Lake Formation). It is a good conceptual intro to PySpark as it then writes the script for you so you can follow along.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the post of the configuration you need, make sure you added the rest of the configuration as at the end I have used `...` to show that there should be a continuation.

```json
{
      "StartAt": "crawler",
      "States": {
        "crawler_name": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Parameters": {
            "Name": "crawler"
          },
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler",
          "Next": "crawler_info",
          "Retry": [
            {
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "BackoffRate": 2,
              "IntervalSeconds": 10,
              "MaxAttempts": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        "crawler_info": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Next": "crawler_status",
          "Parameters": {
            "Name": "crawler"
          },
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:getCrawler",
          "Retry": [
            {
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "BackoffRate": 2,
              "IntervalSeconds": 10,
              "MaxAttempts": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "crawler_status": {
          "Type": "Choice",
          "Choices": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
              "StringEquals": "FAILED",
              "Next": "crawler_failed"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
              "StringEquals": "RUNNING",
              "Next": "crawler_finish_wait"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
              "StringEquals": "STOPPING",
              "Next": "crawler_finish_wait"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
              "StringEquals": "SUCCESS",
              "Next": "glue_job"
            }
          ],
          "Default": "glue_job"
        },
        "crawler_finish_wait": {
          "Type": "Wait",
          "Seconds": 10,
          "Next": "crawler_info"
        },
        "crawler_failed": {
          "Type": "Fail"
        },
        "glue_job": {
          "Type": "Task",
          ...
        }
        ...
}
```

to schedule, use a Eventbridge scheduler :)