# Step Functions - Wait until Glue Crawler is completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

In my team, we manage ETL jobs through Step Functions. As app requirements, we don't want to use Glue Workflows.

Most of our ETL jobs (i.e., step functions) are of the type:

```
Run Crawler on Data Source -> Execute Glue Job -> Run Crawler on Data Target
```

Now, I know that I can run `.synch` for AWS Glue jobs ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-service-integrations.html)), but I can't on Glue Crawlers. My question is: how do I make wait a Step Function until Crawler is done?

I thought about two solutions:

1. A dedicated Lambda periodically checks Crawler state. This is highly inefficient.
2. Step function waits for a CloudWatch event about change on Crawler state (i.e., "Succeed" or "Failed". The issue is I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html) for that. EventBridge supports an event on Crawler State Change which then can trigger something in Step Functions.

Comment: This could be a solution, but I couldn't find a reference about EventBridge being able to listen to this event. Do you have something about this?

Comment: do you know/have any reference how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the Glue Crawler in your statemachine with a Lambda function that triggers the Glue Crawler and keeps running until the statemachine is finished. Then you trigger this Lambda function synchronously in your statemachine.

See this other question on how to implement this approach in Python via the boto3 library. You can adapt the code to be used in an AWS Lambda function:
[Wait until AWS Glue crawler has finished running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996591/wait-until-aws-glue-crawler-has-finished-running/66072347#66072347)