# How to use AWS Lambda synchronously with AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a lambda function that executes a crawler, SNS job and ETL. Is there any way to make the lambda function wait for the crawler to finish first before the SNS and ETL?

Thanks

I currently don't have the IAM access for step functions yet but still require this to be done. Currently it just all executes in one go therefore the SNS and ETL aren't working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072347/12638118) to do it really synchronous (waiting for Glue Crawler to finish inside the Lambda) or, if the Crawler takes to long and the Lambda times out, you create separate Lambdas for starting the crawler and ETL, and let the ETL Lambda be invoked by an EventBridge rule.